# How to delay a promise in when function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

How can I delay a chain of promises? I need this because I want to wait for a CSS animation to complete before going on with the script.

The purpose of the function is to open a view. If the view is not already open, then open it (by changing a class), wait for the css animation, go on. If the view is already open, do nothing and go on.

I want to call the function like this:
(It is a function within an angular controller)

```
$scope.openView(viewId).then(function() {              
     $scope.openAnotherView(anotherViewId);
});


/** Function to open some view **/
$scope.openView = function (viewId) {
    function timeout(delay) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $timeout(resolve, delay);
        });
    }

    // Check if view is already open
    if ($scope.viewId != viewId) {
         $scope.viewId = viewId;             

         // get data from ajaxcall (also a promise)
         return MyService.getData(viewId).then(function(data) {
             // add data to view
             // change class to open view
             // this is working ok!
         }).then(function() { 
             return timeout(30000 /* some large number (testing purpose) */ )
         });
    } else {
         // view is already open, so return here we don't have to wait
         // return empty promise, with no timeout
         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             resolve()
         });     
    }
}
```

This code works, but the delay is not working. Is my approach ok? What am I missing here?

---

**Edit 1**: improved the code with the suggestion from @sdgluck

---

**Edit 2**: Some clarification of the main question:

To clarify the main question a bit more:
Can I use this construction in my code?

```
// code doesnt know wheter to wait or not
// can the Promise do this?
openView().then(function() {              
     openAnotherView();
}
```

*Outcome 1*:

the browser will call `openView()` but since it is already open it will just call `openAnotherView()` right away (no delay).

*Outcome 2* :

The view is not open, so `openView()` will open it, then a delay (or as @Dominic Tobias points out, add an eventlister?) then call `openAnotherView()` after some delay.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit 3**: Added a fiddle with the problem explained
http://jsfiddle.net/C3TVg/60/

Comment: I think you may be going about this the wrong way. It sounds like you might want to detect if the animation is completed like [this](https://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I delay a chain of promises?

`$timeout` returns a promise. **Return** that promise to **chain** it.

```
$scope.openView = function (viewId) {
    // Check if view is already open
    if ($scope.viewId == viewId) {
        //chain right away with empty promise
        return $q.when();
    };

    //otherwise if view is not already open

    var p = MyService.getData(viewId).then(function(data) {
             // add data to view
             // change class to open view
             // this is working ok!
    });

    var pDelayed = p.then (function () {
         //return to chain delay
         return $timeout(angular.noop, 30000);
         });

    //return delayed promise for chaining
    return pDelayed;
};

$scope.openView(viewId).then(function() {
     //use chained promise            
     $scope.openAnotherView(anotherViewId);
});
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I just updated my question. I tried to clarify the fact that I don't now on beforehand if I have to wait.

Comment: Updated to add conditional delay.

Answer (score 13):

To delay a promise, simply call the `resolve` function after a wait time.

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve();
  }, 3000); // Wait 3s then resolve.
});
```

<s>The issue with your code is that you are returning a Promise and then inside the `then` of that Promise you are creating another one and expecting the original promise to wait for it - I'm afraid that's not how promises work. You would have to do all your waiting inside the promise function and then call resolve:</s>

**Edit:** This is not true, you can delay the promise chain in any `then`:

```js
function promise1() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('promise1');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  })
  .then(promise2);
}

function promise2() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('promise2');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function promise3() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('promise3');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

promise1()
  .then(promise3)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('...finished');
  })
```

However that is not a good way to wait for a css animation. It's better to listen to the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event:

```
element.addEventListener('transitionend', onTransitionEnd);
element.classList.add('transition-me');
```

Note if you're using an `animation` instead of a `transition` the same concept applies but use the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) event.

Comment: Using `setTimeout` over `$timeout` doesn't solve the _delay is not working_ issue. But good advice on how to wait for transitions. :-)

Comment: Ah, I indeed disliked having the animation/transition-time duplicated in the css and js. I definitely will look into that! 

About your suggestion: if I add a timeout around the 'add data to view'-functionality and now it waits before opening my view, but it doesnt delay the calling of the first then ('Everything is ready') and the second then ('openAnotherView'). 

I called resolve like this: Promise.resolve();

Comment: So you want to return a promise but you don't want it to wait?

Comment: @DominicTobias, in the first place thanks for your pointers! They really help me to get my head around this issue. I added an explanation of what i'm really trying to achieve (edit 2).

Answer (score 3):

Each [`then` accepts a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) which should return a Promise. It does not accept an instance of Promise. You want to return the call to `timeout`:

```
return MyService
    .getData(viewId)
    .then(function(data) {
        // ...
    })
    .then(function () {
        return timeout(3000);
    });
```

Alternatively, have `timeout` return a function instead of a Promise:

```
 function timeout(delay) {
    return function () {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            //                      ^^^^^^^ (misspelt in your example)
            $timeout(resolve, delay);
        });
    };
}
```

And then you can use it as in your example:

```
return MyService
    .getData(viewId)
    .then(function(data) {
        // ...
    })
    .then(timeout(3000));
```

Comment: Thx for identifying my mistake with the timout function and clearing up how to resolve it. But I think that there is another issue with my code like @Dominic Tobias is pointing out.

Comment: @11mb No problem. And yes, the other answer is more comprehensive. :-)